# Remove slider bar from dynamic_reconfigure

Tags: ros, rqt-reconfigure, ros-kinetic, dynamic-reconfigure

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For doubles and Ints I'd like to remove slider bar from the dynamic reconfigure to only be able to change values via the text  box. For long lists of values I find myself often accidentally bumping the slider (when scrolling with mouse).

Would this difficult to do? I haven't looked too deep into the dyn_reconf code to see whats possible. Any recommendations?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/295648/remove-slider-bar-from-dynamic_reconfigure/) by [shaviland](https://answers.ros.org/users/36154/shaviland/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-06-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can try create an issue [here](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_reconfigure/issues) but it seems the maintainer rather busy at a time so maybe you can change the GUI source code yourself, do pull request so other can use that feature. Try use USB mouse rather than laptop's touch mouse.

---

Originally posted by [achmad_fathoni](https://answers.ros.org/users/32710/achmad_fathoni/) with karma: 96 on 2018-06-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0